# Iterating a JQuery UI Datepicker via CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I want to use CasperJS to click each enabled date in a JQuery UI datepicker, do something while that is clicked, and then go back and click the next date. The problem here is that once I have the datepicker displayed, I don't know how to get the selectors for the anchors within its body and its body only.

I don't think that CasperJS does anything similar to jquery where you can pass it a selector and get an array of elements back.

I could drop into an `evaluate` call and get the array via jquery, but then I'd have to send it back as valid unique selectors for CasperJS to loop over.

I could use jquery to get the content of each anchor, like "1", and then use CasperJS's `clickLabel`, but clickLabel scopes only by tag, so all I could say is "click the anchor whose content is '1'", and then potentially click the wrong thing if there are multiple anchors with the content "1" onscreen.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to do this. XPath can be used to devise a good selector function for the datepicker days like so:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
function daySelector(day) {
    return x("//*[contains(@class,'ui-datepicker')]//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a[text()='"+day+"']");
}
```

Since you know the numbers that you want to click, you can do (*untested*):

```
var numbers = [2,3,4,5,6,7],
    pickerSelector = ".ui-datepicker";
casper.thenEach(numbers, function(num){
    num = num.data;
    // TODO:  click into the date field
    this.waitUntilVisible(pickerSelector);
    this.thenClick(daySelector(num));
    this.waitWhileVisible(pickerSelector);
    // TODO: Check or do something you need
});
```